# Join with 2 temporary table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to create one more temporary table in below query to have join with the same.

```
WITH financial_move_out_due_days AS ( 
    SELECT property_id, 
        management_company_id, 
        value 
    FROM property_preferences 
    WHERE property_id IN ( 112,332 ) AND management_company_id = 23 
    )
    SELECT 
        l.id,
        l.primary_customer_id,
        ( c.name_first || c.name_last ) AS customer_name_full,
        c.email_address AS customer_email_address,
        c.phone_number AS phone_number
    FROM leases l
    JOIN customers c ON ( c.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND c.id = l.primary_customer_id )
    JOIN financial_move_out_due_days fmpodd ON ( fmpodd.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND fmpodd.property_id = l.property_id )
    WHERE
        l.management_company_id = 23
        AND l.property_unit_id IS NOT NULL
        AND l.unit_space_id IS NOT NULL';
```

Comment: I believe you may mean CTE, not temporary table. A CTE is more like a view than a temoporary table, and, in all honesty is usually unnecessary but just syntactic sugar-- it's easier to read, but it usually doesn't do anything you could have done with more complex sql-- just breaks complex sql into pieces. @realnumber3012 has answered your question. Please let he or I know if you need more details.

Comment: Yes. I was not aware about CTE as I am new to PGSQL.

Comment: To `join with the same`, you can just use a single CTE twice. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I got the solution from @realnumber3012 and ramesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
   WITH financial_move_out_due_days AS 
    ( 
        SELECT property_id, 
            management_company_id, 
            value 
        FROM property_preferences 
        WHERE property_id IN ( 112,332 ) AND management_company_id = 23 
    ),
    another_financial_move_out_due_days AS 
    ( 
        SELECT property_id, 
            management_company_id, 
            value 
        FROM property_preferences 
        WHERE property_id IN ( 112,332 ) AND management_company_id = 23 
    )
    SELECT 
        l.id,
        l.primary_customer_id,
        ( c.name_first || c.name_last ) AS customer_name_full,
        c.email_address AS customer_email_address,
        c.phone_number AS phone_number
    FROM leases l
    JOIN customers c ON ( c.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND c.id = l.primary_customer_id )
    JOIN financial_move_out_due_days fmpodd ON ( fmpodd.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND fmpodd.property_id = l.property_id )
    JOIN another_financial_move_out_due_days fmpodd ON ( fmpodd.management_company_id = l.management_company_id AND fmpodd.property_id = l.property_id )
    WHERE
        l.management_company_id = 23
        AND l.property_unit_id IS NOT NULL
        AND l.unit_space_id IS NOT NULL';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH FirstTable AS
(
),
SecondTable AS
(
),
....
```